# Concept issue with objects array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am a very new programer in Android/Java. Below is code that produce a result that is not clear for me. Also, I put the "solution" that I found, but does not satisfy my curiosity.
`

```
//Here I define my class to hold data
public class ImageData {
    Date date;
    byte[] image;
}

// Here I initialize the array photos and put getter and setter
abstract class Variables {
    public static ImageData photos = new ImageData[4];
    static ImageData getPhotos(int n) {
        return photos[n];
    }
    static void setPhotos(ImageData photos, int n) {
        Variables.photos[n] = photos;
    }
}

// Here, at the very begining of app, initialize the array
        Variables.photos[0] = new ImageData();
        Variables.photos[1] = new ImageData();
        Variables.photos[2] = new ImageData();
        Variables.photos[3] = new ImageData();

// And now, I use those objects

    public void run() {// This DOES NOT WORK (all photos have the last image)
        // get 4 photos and save result in global
        int count;
        ImageData localPhoto = new ImageData();
        // clear global (at least the byte[]
        for (count = 0; count > 4; count++) {
            localPhoto.image = null;
            setPhotos(localPhoto, count);
        }
        // take 4 pictures
        for (count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
            localPhoto.image = getPhoto(ipCamera, port);
            localPhoto.date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            setPhotos(localPhoto, count);
        }
        //...............................
    }
```

As I put in comments, all the four photos.image are the same (also the date).
I worked arround using:

```
   public void run() { // This WORKS
        // get 4 photos and save result in global
        int count;
        ImageData localPhoto; // declared, not initialized
        // clear global (at least the byte[] )
        for (count = 0; count > 4; count++) {
            localPhoto = new ImageData(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< NEW
            localPhoto.image= null;
            setPhotos(localPhoto, count);
        }
        // take 4 pictures
        for (count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
            localPhoto = new ImageData(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< NEW
            localPhoto.image = getPhoto(ipCamera, port);
            localPhoto.date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            setPhoto(localPhoto, count);
        }
        //...............................
    }
```

But I really don´t understand why it happens. And also, I would like to initialize the array in a more elegant way, but I could not find.
I would appreciate your comments. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void run() {// This DOES NOT WORK (all photos have the last image)
    // get 4 photos and save result in global
    int count;
    ImageData localPhoto = new ImageData();
```

The above line creates an `ImageData()` object and assigns a reference to it named `localPhoto`.

```
    // clear global (at least the byte[]
    for (count = 0; count > 4; count++) {
        localPhoto.image = null;
```

This sets the `image` field in the object previously created. Note that it sets `image` **in the same object four times**.

```
        setPhotos(localPhoto, count);
```

Now you call `setPhotos()` and pass in the reference to the same object four times.

```
    }
    // take 4 pictures
    for (count = 0; count < 4; count++) {
        localPhoto.image = getPhoto(ipCamera, port);
        localPhoto.date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        setPhotos(localPhoto, count);
```

As in the above description, you are using the reference **to the same object** each time this loop repeats. So all four elements in the array refer to the same object.

```
    }
}
```

Now look at your change

```
    for (count = 0; count > 4; count++) {
        localPhoto = new ImageData(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< NEW
        localPhoto.image= null;
        setPhotos(localPhoto, count);
    }
```

This fixes the problem because you create a new object on each iteration. The reference `localPhoto` is assigned to a different object each time.

To understand this better, read about how reference variables work in Java.

Comment: I agree about the first for loop. localPhoto.image=null should be put outside the loop. But my question is about the second for loop and why the four array elements hold the same image data (the last one).

Comment: Ahh. The first loop make the array's four objects "connected" in some way throu the same localPhoto object (I do not get the correct word).

Comment: Please note, the loop `for (count = 0; count > 4; count++) {` will execute ***zero*** times because the loop condition is backwards.

Comment: Yep. You are right. And passing by reference the same object localPhoto with setPhotos is the cause of the error. Thank you both!!

Comment: `The first loop make the array's four objects "connected"` No, in your first example, you only create **one** object. The array has four **references** to the same object.

Comment: @DanielContarino `The first loop make the array's four objects "connected"` No, in your first example, you only create one object. The array has four references to the same object.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, I am a 68 year EE, who worked mainly with 8bit uC (and tubes in the old times!).My mind try to think in terms of addresses, variables,etc. Objects are a little hard (different) to manupulate, but eventually, will do. Sorry...